# Change name of SQL Server's Service

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I already have SQL Server Pro 2008. I just installed SQL Server 2008 R2 with instance name `sqlserverr2`.

Now, I want to change the name of the service also. I could change name of the server.

```
select @@SERVICENAME, @@SERVERNAME
```

It outputs -

```
SQLEXPRESSR2, HOME\SQLEXPRESS
```

**Means service name is not changed. Only servername changed. Even I cannot use .\sqlexpress to connect from Management Studio.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be very, very careful here!

You are asking to change the name of the Server Service that is controlled by the Service Applet in Windows - Correct?

This would have to be done on a Registry Hack/Tweak..  Problem is that you my have downstream issues if you change it..

Any of the commands preceed with @@ are internal to SQL Server.

You can control many of the Windows Service Options here - http://ss64.com/nt/sc.html

Please be careful..

HTH,

Kent

Answer (score 0):

Assumption here is that you migrated or you used an image and renamed the image to the server. Your DNS name is now different than it was when you first installed SQL Server - Example, you rename your server in the Active Directory.  You get a error for your server name in a job somewhere.   Error might be server_name is invalid.

-- Query to check login

```
SELECT @@SERVICENAME, @@SERVERNAME

sp_dropserver '<oldservername>'
GO


sp_addserver '<newservername>', local;
GO
```

--RESTART THE SERVER
--check again

To change an instance name, just add a slash and the instance name to the above.

Don't forget to restart the sql server service.

SELECT @@SERVERNAME